# How to show many statuses in a windows form

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

The program I'm making will need to show many statuses and websites information. I need to know the best way to go about doing this. I have had 0 luck with tableLayoutPanel.

I would like it to be similar to how [these](http://i.i.com.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2010/09/15/AlienBlueHDScreen_DD_09152010.PNG) are on iOS, but can't find anything similar for C#.

Any help or tips would be VERY appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a TableLayoutPanel. The catch is that you will need to add the rows, and then the controls to the rows, on the fly. You will also have to reorder the rows manually if a row is deleted or moved.

You could also [style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yef90x0.aspx) a datagridview control to look like this, and the datagridview has already done most of the heavy lifting of the databinding for you.

Finally, you may just be able to get away with the [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) control, depending on the functionality you need. This should be the easiest approach